# Operator norm in terms of matrix norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Given a matrix $A$ yielding a linear operator $L$, how can I express the operator norm in terms of $A$'s norm? As far as I've understood, the operator norm in terms of a matrix is given by

> $$
> \|L\|_{op} = \sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_\infty}
> $$

This should mean that
$$
\sup_{x\neq0} \frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_\infty}
= \sup_{x\neq0} \left\|\frac{Ax_{\infty}}{\|x\|_\infty}\right\|_\infty
= \sup_{x\neq0} \left\|A\left(\frac{x_{\infty}}{\|x\|_\infty}\right)\right\|_\infty
$$
However, is there a way to simplify this further, removing any reference to $x$? As I see it, I should be able to reduce $\frac{x_{\infty}}{\|x\|_\infty} \to 1$ somehow. But I don't see quite how?

Comment: $\frac{x}{||x||}$ is not $1$ but a point on the unit sphere $S_1$ in your space. So you can write $||L|| = \sup\limits_{y \in S_1}||Ay||$.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин but $\sup_{y\in S_1} \|Ay\| = \|A1\|$ ?

Comment: No, consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} = 0$. However $A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2} \\ -1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} $. Both a vectors on the unit sphere, but $||Ax||$ for them are different (and greater for the second vector).

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин So I cannot write $\|L\|$ solely in terms of $A$? I must always reference som $y$?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by solely in terms of $A$? The definition of the norm uses vector space on which $A$ acts, you can't get rid of it here. There is a theorem which states that the norm of a matrix is equal to the maximum absolute value of it's eigenvalues but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин: That holds only for normal matrices. In general, you need to take the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$. On a different note, it is an easy exercise to express the norm in the OP just in terms of $A$.

Comment: @Martin you're correct, thanks. I wanted to write singular value but wrote eigenvalue ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call  your norm "the" operator norm: the operator norm given by the 2-norm is way more natural than the one you are using.

For your norm $$\|A\|_{\rm op}=\sup\left\{\|Ax\|_\infty:\ \|x\|_\infty=1\right\},$$ it is very easy to see that 
$$
\|A\|_{\rm op}=\max\left\{\sum_{j=1}^n|A_{kj}|:\ k=1,\ldots,n\right\}.
$$
So $\|A\|_{\rm op}$ is the maximum of the 1-norms of the rows of $A$.

---

For what is very commonly named as "the" operator norm, that is 
$$
\|A\|=\sup\left\{\|Ax\|_2:\ \|x\|_2=1\right\},
$$
one can show (not that easily) that 
$$
\|A\|=\max\{\lambda^{1/2}:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A^*A)\},
$$
where $\sigma(A^*A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A^*A$, i.e., its list of eigenvalues.